# interesting strcmp implementation failure. (C)

Tags: c, pointers, character, strcmp, c-strings

I am working on a small project which I have no access to any C standard library.( building a microkernel in ARM structure from the scratch. Even printf had to be implemented )

Under this circumstance I implemented strcmp, using Duff's machine methodology.

the following is the entire code.

```
int
strcmp ( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
   while ( *str1 || *str2 )
       if ( *(str1++) != *(str2++) ) return *str1 - *str2;
   return 0;
}
```

It made sense; and for some while it seemed to work on test cases, until an end-system fail happened. I traced down and it came to this strcmp.

At first I thought it incremented str1 first then compared against str2 BEFORE str2 incremented. **1. It turned out not to be but could anyone please verify that it can happen in some cases?**

I then figured that the problem was in *str1 - *str2 so changed it to return 1. i.e., the resulting code is as follows:

```
   while ( *str1 || *str2 )
       if ( *(str1++) != *(str2++) ) return 1;
   return 0;
```

while all I wanted was an 'equals' check, so changing into '1' bore no problem, but I still wonder why the original code failed. **2. Could someone give a light or a suggestion as to how it could have failed?** I would rather want the strcmp to follow the standard C interface that it returns a non-zero value that tells more about the str1 and str2.

the test cases were:

```
code_t // a function pointer type
program_find ( char *program )
{
if (strcmp( program, "exit" ) == 0) return ....
else if (strcmp( program, "k1" ) == 0) return ....
else if (strcmp( program, "k3" ) == 0) return ....
else if (strcmp( program, "perf" ) == 0) return ....
else if (strcmp( program, "test_libc" ) == 0) return ....
}
```

when *program was "k3" it returned "k1", and "test_libc" returned "perf".

The original problem was solved by giving it "return 1", so this question is purely for C interests.
A suggestion or linkage to strcmp documentation is also welcome. I have seen the spec interface for IEEE

Comment: What happens when the strings are of unequal length?

Comment: the strings are all null terminated by assumption, so it will be checked because you are comparing to null character at the end.

Comment: check out http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de , an (incomplete) implementation of the C99 standard library from scratch; implementations for the functions from `string.h` can be found here: http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de/trac.fcgi/browser/trunk/functions/string

Answer (score 7):

You are using a post increment on str1 and str2 when doing the comparison.  This causes them to be incremented before doing the subtraction, so you are subtracting the wrong two characters.

A better implementation would be

```
int
strcmp ( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
   while ( *str1 || *str2 ) {
       if ( *str1 != *str2 ) return *str1 - *str2;
       ++str1;
       ++str2;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

- You increment the pointers before performing the subtraction for the return value, so the return value is not correct;
- The standard specific for `strcmp()` indicates that the elements of the strings are compared as `unsigned char`.

Fixing these problems:

```
int
strcmp ( const char *str1, const char *str2 )
{
    const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *)str1;
    const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *)str2;

    while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }

    return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

Comment: you only need to check either `*s1` or `*s2` for zero, because the other case will fail the equality check; see http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de/trac.fcgi/browser/trunk/functions/string/strcmp.c for a reference implementation by DevSolar

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the expression:

```
*(str1++) != *(str2++)
```

Will dereference the pointers `str1` and `str2`, compare the results, then increment both pointers. By the point that the `strcmp` returns, they're now pointing to something different than what you compared.

Keep in mind that implementing `strcmp` to always return 1 or 0 will make it useless for sorting a list of strings! You need to return -1/0/+1 to make it usable for that.

Comment: ah I see. that's why *(str1++) != *(++str2) attempt didn't work out after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
int strcmp(const char* a, const char* b){
    for(;;++a,++b){
        if(*a == '\0' || *b == '\0')
            return (*a == *b)? 0 : *a != '\0' ? 1 : -1;
        if(*a != *b) return (unsigned char)(*a) > (unsigned char)(*b) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```